# How to find the polygon enclosing a point from a set of lines?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, planar-graph

I have a set of non-intersecting lines, some of which are connected at vertices. I'm trying to find the smallest polygon, if one exists, that encloses a given point. So, in the image below, out of the list of all the line segments, given the point in red, I want to get the blue ones only. I'm using Python, but could probably adapt an algorithm from other languages; I have no idea what this problem is called.

[image: Example]

Comment: I don't think the problem statement is correct (unambiguous). The smallest polygon around the red point can be formed by the vertex to the southwest of the point and by the black line segment east of the point.

Comment: What I meant was, the smallest polygon formed only from lines that already exist.

Comment: @JoshSchultz: Even though the bounty expired, what details were you wanting from n.m.'s answer?

Comment: @Teepeemm I was hoping to see an implementation or two, tbh. Perhaps a bit clearer description. I am going to need to implement something like the current top answer, methinks.

Comment: @JoshSchultz I was working on an implementation, but wasn't fast enough before the bounty expired.  FWIW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, remove all line segments that have at least one free endpoint, not coincident with any other segment. Do that repeatedly until no such segment remains.

Now you have a plane nicely subdivided into polygonal areas.

Find a segment closest to your point. Not the closest endpoint but the closest segment, mind you. Find out which direction along the segment you need (your point should be to the right of the directed segment). Go to the endpoint, turn right (that is, take the segment next to the one you came from, counting counterclockwise). Continue going to the next endpoint and turning right until you hit the closest segment again.

Then, check if the polygon encloses the given point. If it is not, then you have found an "island"; remove that polygon and the entire connected component it belongs to, and start over by selecting the nearest segment again. Connected components can be found with a simple DFS.

This gives you a clockwise-oriented polygon. If you want counterclockwise, which is often the default "positive" direction in both the software an the literature, start with the point to your left, and turn left at each intersection.

It surely helps if, given an endpoint, you can quickly find all segments incident with it.

Comment: @WolframH: yes, of course, forgot to add that. A point could be outside of any closed polygon.

Comment: What if the closest line segment is in a different polygon that doesn't enclose the point?

Comment: @Skyler: sorry I keep forgetting to mention important things. it's been a while I've done comp geom algorithms. Answer updated.

Comment: you could brute force construct all possible polygons, then check for inside each.  If its a small problem or you need to repeat for multiple points that may be better than trying to be smart about looking for near edges first.

Comment: @george: yes for multiple points preprocessing should provide some advantage

Comment: "Find a segment closest to your point." - this sounds like the globally closest segment is required, but shouldn't the closest segment *in a given direction* be totally sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

This is really just an implementation of @n.m.'s answer.
This is how far I got before the bounty expired; it's completely untested.

```
def smallestPolygon(point,segments):
    """
    :param point: the point (x,y) to surrond
    :param segments: the line segments ( ( (a,b),(c,d) ) , . . . )
    that will make the polygon
    (assume no duplicates and no intersections)
    :returns: the segments forming the smallest polygon containing the point
    """
    connected = list(segments)

    def endPointMatches(segment1,segment2):
        """
        Which endpoints of segment1 are in segment2 (with (F,F) if they're equal)
        """
        if ( segment1 == segment2 or segment1 == segment2[::-1] ):
            return ( False, False )
        return ( segment1[0] in segment2 , segment1[1] in segment2 )

    keepPruning = True
    while ( keepPruning ):
        keepPruning = False
        for segment in connected:
            from functors import partial
            endPointMatcher = partial(endPointMatches,segment1=segment)
            endPointMatchings = map(endPointMatcher,connected)
            if ( not and(*map(any,zip(*endPointMatchings))) ):
                connected.remove(segment)
                keepPruning = True

    def xOfIntersection(seg,y):
        """
        :param seg: a line segment ( (x0,y0), (x1,y1) )
        :param y: a y-coordinate
        :returns: the x coordinate so that (x,y) is on the line through the segment
        """
        return seg[0][0]+(y-seg[0][1])*(seg[1][0]-seg[0][0])/(seg[1][1]-seg[0][1])

    def aboveAndBelow(segment):
        return ( segment[0][1] <= point[1] ) != ( segment[1][1] <= point[1] )

    # look for first segment to the right
    closest = None
    smallestDist = float("inf")
    for segment in filter(aboveAndBelow,connected):
        dist = xOfIntersection(segment,point[1])-point[0]
        if ( dist >= 0 and dist < smallestDist ):
            smallestDist = dist
            closest = segment

    # From the bottom of closest:
    # Go to the other end, look at the starting point, turn right until
    # we hit the next segment.  Take that, and repeat until we're back at closest.
    # If there are an even number of segments directly to the right of point[0],
    # then point is not in the polygon we just found, and we need to delete that
    # connected component and start over
    # If there are an odd number, then point is in the polygon we found, and we
    # return the polygon
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach.**
I suggest to interpret the input as a [PSLG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_straight-line_graph), G, which consists of vertices and edges. Then your question reduces to finding the face of G that is hit by the point p. This is done by shooting a ray from p to some direction to find an edge of the boundary of the face and traverse the boundary of the face in some direction. However, the first edge hit could be a face that is not hit by p, but itself enclosed by the face hit by p. Hence, we may need to keep search along the ray emanated by p.

**Implementational details.**
In the code below I shoot a ray to east direction and run around the face in clockwise direction, i.e., at each vertex I take the next counter-clockwise edge, until I end up at the first vertex again. The resulting face is returned as a sequence of vertices of G.

If you want to return a [simple polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon) then you have to clean-up the input graph G by pruning of trees in G such that only the simple faces remain.

```
def find_smallest_enclosing_polygon(G, p, simple=False):
  """Find face of PSLG G hit by point p. If simple is True
     then the face forms a simple polygon, i.e., "trees"
     attached to vertices are pruned."""

  if simple:
    # Make G comprise simple faces only, i.e., all vertices
    # have degree >= 2.
    done = False
    while not done:
      done = True
      for v in [v in vertices if degree(v) <= 1]:
        # Remove vertex v and all incident edges
        G.remove(v)
        done = False

  # Shoot a ray from p to the east direction and get all edges.      
  ray = Ray(p, Vector(1, 0))
  for e in G.iter_edges_hit(ray):

    # There is no enclosing face; p is in the outer face of G
    if e is None:
      return None

    # Let oriented edge (u, v) point clockwise around the face enclosing p
    u, v = G.get_vertices(e)
    if u.y < v.y
       u, v = v, u

    # Construct the enclosing face in clockwise direction
    face = [u, v]
    # While not closed
    while face[-1] != face[0]:
      # Get next counter-clockwise edge at last vertex at last edge.
      # If face[-1] is of degree 1 then I assume to get e again.
      e = G.get_next_ccw_edge(face[-2], face[-1])
      face.append(G.get_opposite_vertex(e, face[-1]))

    # Check whether face encloses p.
    if contains(face, p):
       return face

  return None
```

**Complexity.**
Let n denote the number of vertices. Note that in a PSLG the number of edges are in O(n). The pruning part may take O(n^2) time the way it is implemented above. But it could be one in O(n) time by identifying the degree-1 vertices and keep traversing from those.

The ray intersection routine can be implemented trivially in O(n) time. Constructing the face takes O(m) time, where m is the size of the polygon constructed. We may need to test multiple polygons but the sum of sizes of all polygons is still in O(n). The test contains(face, p) could be done by checking whether face contains an uneven number of edges returned by G.iter_edges_hit(ray), i.e., in O(m) time.

With some preprocessing you can build up a data structure that finds the face hit by p in O(log n) time by classical [point location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location#Planar_case) algorithms in computational geometry and you can store the resulting polygons upfront, for the simple and/or non-simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this a number of times with the same lines and different points, it would be worthwhile preprocessing to figure out all the polygons. Then it's straightforward: draw a line from the point to infinity (conceptually speaking). Every time the you cross a line, increment the crossing count of each polygon the line is a part of. At the end, the first polygon with an odd crossing count is the smallest enclosing polygon. Since any arbitrary line will do just as well as any other (it doesn't even need to be straight), simplify the arithmetic by drawing a vertical or horizontal line, but watch out for crossing actual endpoints.

You could do this without preprocessing by creating the polygons as you cross each line. This basically reduces to n.m.'s algorithm but without all the special case checks.

Note that a line can belong to two polygons. Indeed, it could belong to more, but it's not clear to me how you would tell: consider the following:

```
+---------------------------+
|                           |
|   +-------------------+   |
|   |                   |   |
|   |   +-----------+   |   |
|   |   |           |   |   |
|   |   |           |   |   |
+---+---+-----------+---+---+
```

Comment: How many polygons would you consider in your example - 3 or 6? How do you find them?

Comment: There are 3 *minimal* polygons (those that are not parts of other polygons) and exactly 6 segments belong to two polygons each (the two inner &Pi;-shaped polylines).

Comment: @WolframH: There are three polygons, certainly. If you don't know which ones there are, then you have to assume that no polygon includes another. But had the two outer polygons dropped a fraction of a pixel down (two fractions for the outermost one) then you'd have a different reading.

Comment: @n.m.: I somewhat agree, but how do you define "not parts of other polygons" in a way that excludes islands? Just curious, really... I don't think you can produce any other answer than yours by analysing the individual line segments.

Comment: @rici: For consistency it is best to operate in terms of polygons with holes. Then islands are not a problem, they are not a part of some other polygon, they just fit in some hole. The implementation is somewhat more complex though. My algorithm does not compute holes. If holes are desirable, they have to be searched for e.g. like follows: given a polygon, start checking all vertices not belonging to it. If a vertex lies inside that polygon, find an eliminate its connected component, then find its outer border; it is a hole. Then check the next remaining vertex etc.